# Connecting Nokia 106 to Arduino

Tags: serial

I was wondering if this can be done. I got a Nokia 106 and am trying to make it talk, but the audio jack doesn't seem to cooperate and the Fbus pins are right under the SIM slot, which is right under the battery. Any advice?

Added: It seems that it talks AT commands, since it is a GSM model, but I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: Hi, can you give us some information on the communication protocol of the Nokia? It's impossible to tell you if its possible to talk to the Arduino if we don't know how it talks.

Comment: @sachleen There's actually not much info out there. The phone was release on August 2013, so there doesn't seem to be much research. I found out about the Fbus here: http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f148/nokia-105-new-100-working-solution-1731398/

Comment: @sachleen Sorry for the difficult question. I'm kinda new to this and I don't want to screw up the cellphone… to much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the picture of the Nokia FBUS connector from your link:
[image]

And here's a (slightly dubious) method of connection from some random web page
[image]

which goes on to say

> The F-bus protocol uses 115,200bps so we can easily use the Arduino’s serial function to communication with the phone. All you need to is hook up the phones TX to the Arduino’s RX and then use a resistor divider (I choose 330 ohm resistors) to connect the Arduino’s TX to the phones RX as shown above.

That page goes on to show how to use an Arduino to get the phone to send SMS text messages.

Sources:

- http://www.insidegadgets.com/2013/01/12/how-to-use-nokia-f-bus-to-send-an-sms-message/
- http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f148/nokia-105-new-100-working-solution-1731398/

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I'd need to pretty much tear the cellphone apart. I'd rather not kill my phone :/

Answer (score -1):

just trim the actual simcard, so its level with 'microsim insert' back edge. Its what i did on my Nokia 100/GPO 746 project, works fine, wont kill the phone